# Python in operator is not working

Tags: python, list, boolean, function

When I run this code, nothing shows up. For example I call `ind(1, [1, 2, 3])`, but I don't get the integer `13`.

```py
def ind(e, L):
    if (e in L == True):
        print('13')
    else: 
        print('12')
```

Comment: You should be getting an error actually. In Python it is `True`, not `true`.

Comment: `if e in L:` is just enough.

Comment: Extract a minimal example before asking here, see also the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator precedence. If you put `(` and `)` around `e in L` it will work:

```
def ind(e, L):
    if ((e in L) == True):
        print('13')
    else:
        print('12')

ind(1, [1, 2, 3])
```

But testing for `True` can be done (and is the usual idiom) done without the `True`

```
def ind(e, L):
    if (e in L):
        print('13')
    else:
        print('12')

ind(1, [1, 2, 3])
```

Edit: as a bonus you can even use `True` and `False` to keep/nullify things. With your example:

```
def ind(e, L):
    print('13' * (e in L) or '12')

ind(1, [1, 2, 3])

ind(4, [1, 2, 3])
```

And this ouputs:

```
13
12
```

Because `e in L` has first been evaluated to `True` and `13 * True` is `13`. The 2nd part of the boolean expression is not looked up.

But when calling the function with `4`, then the following happens:

```
`13` * (e in L) or '12` -> `13` * False or '12' -> '' or '12' -> 12
```

Becase and empty string evaluates to `False` too and therefore the 2nd part of the `or` boolean expression is returned.

Comment: Although `'13' * (e in L) or '12'` works here, a more general solution that works on operands that don't support `*` is `e in L and '13' or '12'`. Or, using a conditional expression to make it more readable: `'13' if e in L else '12'`. Another option is `('12', '13')[e in L]`, although that's probably the least readable of the options.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
def ind(e, L):
    if (e in L):
       print ('13')
    else:
       print ('12')
```

Here ind(1,[1,2,3]) will print 13

And here's my proof that the above syntax runs in my machine:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you test that.

Comment: 1) You can't use the Python keyword `in` as a name for a function (or anything else). 2) You don't need parentheses around the `if` condition, and it's normal Python style to omit them.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I run the entire thing before I placed my answer.

Comment: You made a typo in the name of your function , look again! `in`?

Comment: @bigOTHER Edited. :) Thanks

Comment: So you ran it... did you forget to actually look at the result, or did you simply post it even though it was a syntax error?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think it was just a typo in his writing in SO

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was rushing when I typed :) Because I was doing some thesis/latex stuff when I come across the question here.