# Why does this not work as an array membership test?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
>>> 5 in [1, 2, 3, 4] == False
False
```

I get that this is a bizarre way to test membership, and that

```
>>> 5 not in [1, 2, 3, 4]
True
```

is the "correct" way.  What confuses me is that its behavior is different from both

```
>>> (5 in [1, 2, 3, 4]) == False
True
```

and

```
>>> 5 in ([1, 2, 3, 4] == False)
TypeError ...
```

Have I missed something obvious?  (Tested in Python 2.7 and Python 3.4).

To clarify, I understand the last three snippets.  I am asking about the behavior of the **first** snippet, and why it is different.

Comment: This is definitely a dupe, but I can't find an appropriate dupe candidate.

Comment: OK... then how do you know it's a dupe?

Comment: @user2357112 - [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824578/python-in-operator-is-not-working) seems close.

Comment: @user2357112 - Found a good one.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: The question is a dupe, but the answers to that one suck. None of them explain anything.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I see you found a better one to mark as dupe. I had a feeling Martijn had written a good answer on the topic.

Comment: @user2357112 - Ah, you meant the initial guess. Yeah, that one wasn't suitable. The one I ended up using is right on target. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a chained comparison. You may have known that you can do

```
1 < 2 < 3
```

in Python, and it's equivalent to `(1 < 2) and (2 < 3)`. (Or maybe you didn't. Now you know.) Well, the same thing applies to `in` and `==`.

```
5 in [1, 2, 3, 4] == False
```

is equivalent to

```
(5 in [1, 2, 3, 4]) and ([1, 2, 3, 4] == False)
```

Since `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is not equal to `False`, the whole expression evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Awesome!  I know about chained comparisons; I didn't realize they applied to `in`.  Good answer!

Comment: This is such a common wat.  I actually tried to get `in` and `not in` documented as [comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), since they are literally *defined* as comparisons in the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), but did not get much support on bugs.python.org

Comment: I was thinking about making the lack of documentation a bug report too; I guess it's a lost cause.  Any idea why it's a comparison operator?  I can't think of any case where this behavior is useful.

Comment: @IanKuehne: I'm guessing it was just convenient for the implementation to stick them in with the other comparison operators, and they didn't care too much about the chaining behavior.

Comment: The last sentence is wrong. Already `5 in [1, 2, 3, 4]` is `False`, and `and` short-circuits, so `[1, 2, 3, 4] == False` doesn't even get evaluated at all.