# Strange 'in' operator behaviour in Python

Tags: python, operator-keyword

Just today I came accross about this strange behaviour of the `in` operator in Python (using Python 3.6.3 to be more specific).

```py
>>> ':' in '4:2'
True
>>> ':' in '4:2' != True
True
>>> (':' in '4:2') != True
False
>>> ':' in ('4:2' != True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

As it can be seen, `':' in '4:2'` is `True`. Everything normal here. But the strange behaviour appears in the second line:

```py
>>> ':' in '4:2' != True
True
```

`':' in '4:2'` is `True`, which `!= True` and results in… `True`? If we group by hand to ensure the precedence:

```py
>>> (':' in '4:2') != True
False
```

Results in `False`. `True != True` is `False` as expected. Then, how did we get the `True` before?:

```py
>>> ':' in ('4:2' != True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

What's going on?

Comment: Related: [Why does this not work as an array membership test? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40987185/953482) and [Why does the expression 0 < 0 == 0 return False in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6074018/953482)

Comment: ':' in '4:2' != True: chaining operators

Comment: Well I knew about chaining operators like less (or equal to)/greater than, I just didn't know they applied to `in` too. How is this a duplicate for that question? It's clearly a different operator.

Comment: When you explicitly put parentheses around it, you see the order in which you think the operators are evaluated. Without them you still think they are evaluated left to right, but they are not. Take a look here https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Semantically, `in` isn't a comparison operator, but syntactically it's treated like one, and so it participates in comparison chaining.

Comment: @Lonami It would be considered a duplicate since the answer to that question is "because of operator chaining", and there is no need to answer the same thing again for every other combination of operators.

Comment: @bgse I still can't see very well how "in" can chain at all with the rest operators. I think an answer on why this works like this for this case makes more sense than letting people figure out a completely different operator, more when `<` is so different from `in` (which accepts an iterator on the right side).

Comment: The duplicate 40987185 does make more sense. Thanks, I guess.

Comment: FWIW, there's nothing wrong with asking a question that gets closed as a dupe (provided it's not a really obvious dupe & you've done a search beforehand to find an existing question that addresses your problem). We close such questions because we don't want the answers to be scattered all over the place. It's much better if most of the relevant answers are in one place where people can easily compare and contrast them, and where those answers can be voted on as a group.

Comment: @Lonami, hopefully this helps.... `4 < 5 < 6` chains out to become `4 < 5 and 5 < 6`. Now we know that is true. You can also see that `4 < (5 < 6)` becomes `False` because what is inside parentheses is explicitly evaluated first.

Using this on your example of `':' in '4:2' != True` this chains out to be  `':' in '4.2' and '4.2' != True `. Once again, if you put the parentheses around it you no longer have a chained comparison.

I hope this clears it up for you.

Comment: Yes, thanks @ZWiki. The first duplicate they linked was a bit strange but the second made more sense.