# Python function that takes a list and returns a new list with unique elements of the first list

Tags: python, list, unique

I'm trying to solve this problem by using this code

```
def unique_list(numbers):
    unique = []
    for item in numbers :
        if item in unique == False:
            unique.append(item)
    return unique
```

But every time i'm calling this function, I get an empty list
Can somebody help thus beginner ? I don't understand where i'm going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Actually, as pointed out by [DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace) below, this is wrong! Curiously, It isn't evaluated as `(item in unique) == False` nor as `item in (unique == False)`.

<s>It's caused by operator precedence. In the line:</s>

```
item in unique == False:
```

<s>Python first resolves the `unique == False` expression, which checks if the variable `unique` is equals to `False` (which isn't true, it is a list).</s>

<s>So, that line becomes</s>

```
if item in False:
```

<s>So, the if block is never executed!</s> To fix it, you can wrap `item in unique` in parenthesis, such as:

```
if (item in unique) == False:
```

BUT, there's a very useful data structure in Python that serves your purpose: Set. A Set holds only unique values, and you can create it from a existing list! So, your function can be rewritten as:

```
def unique_list(numbers):
   return list(set(numbers)) # It converts your original list into a set (with only unique values) and converts back into a list
```

Comment: This is wrong. If the line was evaluated as `if item in False` then a `TypeError` would have been raised (`type 'bool' is not iterable`), It is quite interesting that `if item in unique == False` is **not** evaluated as `(item in unique) == False` **nor** as `item in (unique == False)`

Comment: Oooooh you're right, thanks! I wonder how it is actually evaluated?

Comment: It is a comparison chaining, much like `1 < item < 3`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798572/unexplained-behavior-of-int-in-boolean-construct and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987185/why-does-this-not-work-as-an-array-membership-test

Answer (score 2):

As *Oksana* mentioned, use `list(set(numbers))`.
As for you code, change `if item in unique == False` to `if item not in unique`. But note that this code is slower, since it has to scan the list for every new element that it tries to add:

```
def unique_list(numbers):
    unique = []
    for item in numbers :
        if item not in unique:
            unique.append(item)
    return unique

print(unique_list([1, 2, 3, 1, 2]))
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: According to PEP8 `if item not in unique` is more idiomatic than `if not item in unique` and should be preferred.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thank you for suggesting the more idiomatic `if item not in unique`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As SET only contain unique value, we can use it to get your answer.

> Use this python function code

```
def unique_list(numbers):
 x=set(numbers)           #unique numbers in set
 y=list(x)                #convert set to list as you want your output in LIST.
 print(y)
```

EXAMPLE:

```
unique_list([2,2,3,3,3])
```

OUTPUT Will be a unique list.

```
[2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot check if the item in unique is false or true like that, instead we use 'not'. Try this:

```
if not item in unique:
      unique.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def unique_list(lst):
    a = set(lst) 
    return list(a)
```