# Unexplained behavior of '<int> in [] == <boolean>' construct

Tags: python

Consider

```
1 in [] == False
```

On a very quick glance, it appears that this will raise a `TypeError: bool is not iterable`, but it actually executes (and evaluates to `False` if you are curious, which is also a bit surprising).

However,

```
1 in [1] == False
```

is also evaluating to `False`.

It is interesting to note that `1 in [] == False` does **not**:

- Evaluate as `1 in ([] == False)` - This causes the expected `TypeError` mentioned above.
- Evaluate as `(1 in []) == False` - This can be confirmed by `(1 in []) == False` which outputs `True`, compared to `1 in [] == False` which evaluates to `False`.

The only output that does make sense is `(1 in [1]) == False` which is `False`.

`dis.dis` outputs:

```
dis.dis('1 in [] == False')
print()
print()
print()
dis.dis('(1 in [1]) == False')
print()
print()
print()
dis.dis('1 in ([] == False)')
```

outputs

```
  # 1 in [] == False
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
             14 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE


  # (1 in [1]) == False
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ((1,))
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE


  # 1 in ([] == False)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

I'm especially intrigued by the `ROT_THREE`, `ROT_TWO` and `JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP` instructions.

Comment: It's comparison chaining, `(1 in []) and ([] == False)`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons.

Comment: I'm out of votes, but dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40987185/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe ahh of course! that explains the `JUMP` (the chain is shortcircuited from left to right). Didn't expect to be able to use chaining with `in`. Thanks! and don't worry, will gladly mark this as a dupe on your behalf (edit: someone beat me to it).

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah, it is really not intuitive to me that `in` counts as a comparison operator, but I guess it makes sense. But still in my mind, *comparison* operators should just be <, >, ==, >=, <=, and !=

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah.. I guess that "learning a new thing every day" is not a cliche