# Compare result of "in statement" with bool in Python, why 1 in [1] == True results with False?

Tags: python

```py
print(1 in [1] == True)  # False Why??????????????????
print((1 in [1]) == True)  # True OK
print(1 in ([1] == True))  # TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable OK
```

So just what is happening here? How Python interprets this statement?

Comment: Your first line is an example of a *chained comparison* - it's equivalent to `(1 in [1]) and ([1] == True)` (except that the shared part of the two sub-expressions, `[1]` in this case, is only evaluated once).  This is more commonly used in forms like `0 <= x < 100`, but it works with any comparison operators - and `in` is one of them.

Comment: Could you please write an answer (not comment) to accept?

Comment: It's a duplicate, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40987185/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6074018/3001761

Comment: Actually comparison with exactly True or False is quite confusing in this case, so not sure it's a full dublicate.